# Redirect from folder to main page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I know it should be quite easy but I can't do it at all.

I have some websites linking to:
www.mydomain.com/projects/xxx.html and may other .html pages.

The folder projects doesn't exist anymore.

How can I redirect from: www.mydomain.com/projects to www.mydomain.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new projects folder and put the following in a .htaccess file in it, replacing example.com with whatever your domain is.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^projects(/.*)?$ / [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: NC would only be safe if this is a Windows machine - otherwise, there's a small possibility that it would match URLs that shouldn't be matched (like on the off-chance there was a Projects folder as well as a projects folder).

Comment: There are many filesystems that won't allow `Projects` to be created if `projects` already exists.